# Pointing a godaddy domain name to amazon hosting

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-route53

1. I have a domain name mydomain.com, which is from godaddy. I have a hosting plan from AWS.
2. I have the nameservers, got from 'Route 53 hosted zone' which are in the format as below:
   ns-123.awsdns-11.com
   ns-123.awsdns-22.org
   ns-123.awsdns-33.net
   ns-123.awsdns-44.co.uk
3. I added the above nameservers in the nameservers options in the manage nameservers section of godaddy.
4. Its been around a week but i am still not able to see my content live for mydomain.com. Unable to understand if i am missing anything.
   I referred [this link](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-route-my-GoDaddy-domain-name-to-my-Amazon-EC2-web-server).

Comment: If i hit the url 'mydomain.com' the browser says, 'DNS address could not be found'.

Comment: Is mydomain.com configured on your server? (There are several ways to do this depending on what you're using to control your server.)

Comment: Yes, I have created a bucket at aws s3, after that i have also set the permissions for mydomain.com in the Bucket Policy Editor